# Getting KeyCode in GotFocus event?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

C# WinApps: Is there any way that I can check if something like CTRL-V is pressed but not in the KeyDown,PreviewKeyDown,KeyPress,etc ... events? those are being eaten by some other parts in my App and it is so hard to find them so I thought Ok for this contorl lets check the pressed keys in its GotFocus event! Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the events being "eaten".  Events can call multiple handlers.  So even if the event is already being subscribed to by one handler, you can subscribe to it with another handler and it should work just fine.

Another option would be to subclass the control you are using and use the subclass instead.  Then you can override the On{event} methods and do anything you want with those (be sure to call the base method as well to ensure the behavior of the original class is still in place).

HTH

Comment: I'm guessing eaten by other forms/controls that are focused. Sounds like he wants a global way to capture all keystrokes sent to his application, regardless of focus.

Comment: thanks, well for example I want a KeyDown for an activex control on my form, so I go and add it but it never gets called. so I thought maybe I can use its GotFocus event which for sure gets called (ManagedSpy showed it is getting called and KeyDown,etc are not  getting called)